# Function to search multiple keys in an associative Array?

Tags: php, arrays, laravel-5.1

I have an array in this format:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [NUMBER] => 1 [AMOUNT] => 5 [RATE] => 1 ) [1] => Array ( [NUMBER] => 2 [AMOUNT] => 10 [RATE] => 1 ) [2] => Array ( [NUMBER] => 3 [AMOUNT] => 15 [RATE] => 1 ) )
```

I can loop thru array and can find the desired result but I am rather looking for some `builtin` function or function provided by `Laravel`.

Is there efficient and small way to search this array if it's given two inputs: *NUMBER = 3* and *AMOUNT = 5* then it returns either true/false or that particular value?

Comment: What is your expected output? What you have tried so far Post your attempts too?

Comment: return $arr['NUMBER']==3 && $arr['AMMOUNT']==5;

Comment: @Uchiha I could loop thru arrays and find values but issue is that some `built-in` function or function provided by `Laravel` to perform this job.

Comment: you could try `array_filter`, but this function will return a filtered array instead of true/false.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
echo count(
    array_filter(
        $your_array, 
        function ($e) {
            return $e['NUMBER'] == 3 && $e['AMOUNT'] == 5;
        }
    )
);
```

should do the trick

Test:

```
$fooArray = array(
    array(
        'NUMBER' => 1,
        'AMOUNT' => 5
    ),
    array(
        'NUMBER' => 2,
        'AMOUNT' => 10,
    ),
    array(
        'NUMBER' => 3,
        'AMOUNT' => 15
    )
);

$barArray = array(
    array(
        'NUMBER' => 1,
        'AMOUNT' => 5
    ),
    array(
        'NUMBER' => 2,
        'AMOUNT' => 10,
    ),
    array(
        'NUMBER' => 3,
        'AMOUNT' => 5
    )
);

echo count(
    array_filter(
        $fooArray, 
        function ($e) {
            return $e['NUMBER'] == 3 && $e['AMOUNT'] == 5;
        }
    )
);
//will echo 0

echo count(
    array_filter(
        $barArray, 
        function ($e) {
            return $e['NUMBER'] == 3 && $e['AMOUNT'] == 5;
        }
    )
);
//will echo 1
```

---

If you want the true/false logic, just add a `(true == )` or `(false == )` test instead of echoing it

Comment: Short and Sweet. I tried `array_intersect` but give `Array to String Conversion` error.